# Objects of different programming languages

Tags: programming-languages, php, object-oriented, javascript, python

Apparently, there are some resemblance between objects in JavaScript and dictionaries in Python. Each language defines an object a little different (and there is some logic that all definitions to be the same as in physics).

How are objects alike and how do they differ between JavaSscript, Python and PHP?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to get at - does [Why many programming languages have only 2 data-structures: arrays and hashes?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191653/why-many-programming-languages-have-only-2-data-structures-arrays-and-hashes) address what you are asking?

Comment: how is this any different from human languages? Sure there are commonalities, but you basically just said, "I like all definitions to be the same... how come word for 'chair' is different in every language?"... maybe because it is what it is?

Comment: are they? I am asking what is precisely the difference between the objects definitions in those languages syntax-wise and in the real application into the machine primitives storage

Comment: the syntax in languages in Latin is virtually the same. maybe this differences are just a time hazzard because those language exist for a very short time. really i don't know i try to understand it too

Comment: @sivi - you can still run with that analogy. Latin is the root of all languages just like concept of objects also has common roots. But then every country (i.e. community that developed a particular language) saw a need to tweak some definitions/spellings here and there.  They do it because a) they might see they have some kind of special need; b) because maybe they didn't like Latin all that much to begin with and always thought it could be done better; c) because they had to do something and simply picked a syntax and went with it. I'd say just pick a specific language that you find...

Comment: ... interesting and learn it, rather than try to look at 5+ of them to determine what the common denominator is.  Once you learn one and then switch over to the other one, the common denominator part will become clear to you without even having to think about it.

Comment: yes i know but it is easier for me to understand things from the general perspective. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects really represent the same thing in all three languages: a bundling of state and operations. What truly differs is their implementation of this idea.

The largest difference is that Python & PHP are class-based object-oriented systems, meaning that the "templates" for objects are pre-defined. When a new intance of one of these templates or classes is initialized, the class's pattern or definition is used to shape the newly initialized object.

In JavaScript, the object system is prototype based. Rather than having some definition as to how objects of the same type ought to be defined and initialized, JavaScript takes a special object, a prototype, and clones it to create a new instance of that class.

All three languages are dynamic, which sets them apart from the C#/Java ecosystem in that you still have a good deal more flexibility. In JavaScript, Python and PHP you can dynamically add new properties and even functions at runtime whereas this is not truly possible in C#/Java.

See the following links for more information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming

Comment: I disagree. Object-Orientation is fundamentally about Data Abstraction, more precisely Procedural Data Abstraction. Inheritance is completely orthogonal. You can have OO without inheritance and you can have inheritance without OO. And *how* this Data Abstraction is achieved is *fundamentally* different between JavaScript and Python & PHP. In Python & PHP, Data Abstraction is provided by *Objects*, in JavaScript, it is provided by *Functions* (more precisely: *Closures*). Really, JS objects aren't objects, they are dictionaries. Objects are implemented using JS objects + Closures.

Comment: i would love to read more of your and other points of view of this issue

Comment: Dictionaries and arrays are distinct types in Python while in JavaScript, dictionaries and arrays are just objects with prototypes already defined for you.  You can add arbitrary properties to an JavaScript Array.  You cannot in Python.

Comment: You can sort of do this in C# as well with ExpandoObject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx (also the name is just  awesome :P)